I have the problem in solving the SDP with CVXR
A = rbind(c(10,3),c(3,10))
B = rbind(c(6,-4),c(-4,10))
C = rbind(c(8,1),c(1,6))
D = rbind(c(16,-13),c(-13,60))

library(CVXR)

x <- Variable(3)

obj <- Minimize(x[1]+x[2]-x[3])

con <- list( x[1]*A + x[2]*B + x[3]*C <= D,
        x>=0) 

pro9 <- Problem(obj,con)

sol <- solve(pro9)

sol

sol$value
sol$getValue(x)

I got value=Inf, x=NA
reference answer
sol$value: -1.486487e+00
sol$getValue(x): ## [1] -4.726329e-06 -1.245669e-06  1.486481e+00
I do not have a idea what problem is.
Please let me know the problem.
Thank you in advance.
